# How to create list by deriving another list in scala

Tags: scala

I have list as follow

```
List[String] = List(Gateway = MSC050, Sequence = 176484,Gateway = MSC050, Sequence = 176485)
```

I want to create another by referring above as follow

```
List[String] = List(50176484,50176485)
```

Here I have merger last two digit of Gateway and Sequence together into another list. Can any one help on this?

Comment: Did you try look at scala collection api? https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html This should simple task to do.

Comment: Are you sure you have a list of String? If so, pleas add the " signs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list is missing the quotes:

```
  val input: List[String] = List("Gateway = MSC050", "Sequence = 176484", "Gateway = MSC050", "Sequence = 176485")

  input.grouped(2).map {
    l => l(0).takeRight(2) + l(1).split(' ').last
  }.toList
```

Output:

```
List(50176484, 50176485)
```

`grouped(2)` will allow you to iterate over every Gateway/Sequence pair. Then you need to get the last two digits from the Gateway, and the number from the Sequence. I've done this with `takeRight` for the Gateway, and splitting on spaces for the sequence (assuming that your Sequence strings will always have a space after the equals).

Answer (score 0):

```
val original: List[String] = List("MSC050", "176484", "MSC051", "176485")

val modified = original.grouped(2).map(el => el(0).takeRight(2) + el(1)).toList
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)